# How to connect to H2 Console from Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

```
driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
username=sa
password=sa

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Wrong username or password why?

[image]

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
debug=true

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

see this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)